# React Native Facebook SDK ShareDialog asks to login again

Tags: facebook, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I'm currently doing a project using react native where I need to let users to login using facebook. So I use [React-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) `LoginButton` component to let users to login and get the access token. Also part of the project needs let users to share links to their profiles.

In order to do that, I followed as [GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) of Facebook which says how to add ShareDialog. After adding both `LoginButton` and `ShareDialog`, I ran the app. Login was successful and I got the access token. But when I try to share a link, it asks me to login again. If I login with ShareDialog, it let me to share post and everything as expected.

But if I logout with `LoginButton` after login with ShareDialog too, both components perform logout successfully. Problem is Login does not handle for both components with single login.

Below is my code.

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <LoginButton
      publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
      onLoginFinished={
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            alert("Login failed with error: " + error.message);
          } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            alert("Login was cancelled");
          } else {
            alert("Login was successful with permissions: " + result.grantedPermissions)
          }
        }
      }
      onLogoutFinished={() => alert("User logged out")}/>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.shareLinkWithShareDialog}>
      <Text style={styles.shareText}>Share link with ShareDialog</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
 );
}

shareLinkWithShareDialog = () => {

const shareLinkContent = {
  contentType: 'link',
  contentUrl: 'https://www.sample.com/',
  contentDescription: 'Test Sharing Description'
};
 var tmp = this;
 ShareDialog.canShow(shareLinkContent).then(
 (canShow) => {
    if (canShow) {
      return ShareDialog.show(shareLinkContent);
    }
  }
).then(
 (result) => {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Share cancelled');
    } else {
      alert('Share success with postId: ' + result.postId);
    }
  },
 (error) => {
    alert('Share fail with error: ' + error);
  }
 );
}
```

Please help me here. I cannot identify what's wrong with this.

**Note**

I checked this using a [Test User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/) of Facebook and it also has all relevant permissions including `manage_pages` and test user has it's own [Test Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar problem and that was because I hadn't installed facebook app on my phone. Seems like your code is fine.

However I haven't used Test Page and Test User options in facebook but I hope they are no different than a normal user when it comes to functionalities. Just try to install the facebook app and run your app. Should be fine.

Comment: Oh cool. It works fine now. Thanks alot. But that would be a problem if the user didn't have facebook app installed. Wouldn't it?